# Alternatives to RepRap project?

Tags: desktop-printer, rapid-prototyping, open-source, replicating-printers

I would like to print 3D desktop printer, but currently I know only [RepRap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RepRap_project) project. Ideally I'm looking for some better quality or larger alternatives (e.g. for printing larger parts than RepRap allows).

Are there any?

Comment: Did you look on github or any of the standard 3D model sharing sites? There are tons of options (not necessarily affiliated with the reprap project) for printers large and small.

Comment: The answer to this question is "Yes." A complete answer would fill a book.  If we are to allow printer recommendations on this site, we must insist you provide a set of requirements that narrows the field down to, at most, a few machines.

Comment: I agree with @AdamDavis, but I also want to know what alternatives there are, so I still care to see an answer

Comment: @deltree Consider contributing an answer to the question here: http://meta.3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/5/how-do-we-handle-recommendations

Comment: @AdamDavis - I actually took for granted that the OP meant other projects of self-replicating printers ("I would like to print 3D desktop printer", they say), not "other printers" in general.  It seemed like a fairly interesting question to me, in that case.